How to make sure the empty folders are also copied from source storage account to target storage account in ADF copy data activity?
Copy Data Activity - Source:

Copy Data Activity - Sink:

How to make sure the empty folders are also copied from source storage account to target storage account in ADF copy data activity?
I tried keeping the '*' mark in file path type - wildcard file path but empty folders are missing in the target storage account.

Are you using blob storage account or ADLS gen2 account?

Blob Storage account (GPv2)

According to this Azure blob storage doesn't support empty folders, that may be the reason for empty folders are missing in the target storage account. If you want to work with Empty folders check Enable hierarchical namespace while creating storage account as shown below:

Then the storage account behaves like ADLS gen2 account and it will support empty folders. If the target storage account is already created, then upgrade it ADLS gen2 by using option Data Lake Gen2 upgrade as shown below:

Then you will be able to copy empty folders successfully as shown below:


Upvoted the answer because of clear info. But we cannot upgrade to ADLS2 because this storage account is specifically created for AML workspace provisioning. AML will not work if the storage account is ADLS2 type., Thanks. If you have any alternativce solution for copying the missing empty folders, please provide me. I'll update my lead with your answer and accept the solution in the next few minutes. Thanks for your help :-)

Didn't et any upvote for my answer, as of now, you can't work with empty folders in blob storage account, you have to use ADLS account to work with empty folders.

I'm eligible to upvote only when I get 20 Reputations so it didn't reflect for you - you may upvote my question for that. But, thanks for the answer, it's Beneficial.
